# Spring and Hikari: Transaction with long non transactional operation inside

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have to write an operation to database only if a subsequent (non transactional) operation succeeds.

The condition is that the operation (let's say, send an e-mail) is slow, and I want to rollback de transaction if this operation fails. The structure is very simple:

```
@Transactional         // A transaction starts and a connection is taken.
public void  doStuff(String text) {
    
    writeToDataBase(text);
    
    sendEmail(text);   //Rollback previous operation if this fails.
}
```

It works fine like this, the problem is that if the "sendEmail(text)" operation is slow, then the database connection keeps blocked until this operation finishes, the transaction is commited and the connection released.

I am performing load tests and the connection seems to be behaving in a way that I dont understand, it throws this error:

Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@50e5e340 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(72000), ErrorCode(1013)

How should this kind of logic be managed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace for the connection error pls?